# Can't start Elasticsearch as a service

Tags: ubuntu, service, elasticsearch

I am trying to install Elasticsearch (0.90.5) as a service in my ubuntu (12.04) machine.

I tried

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.5.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-0.90.5.deb
```

It gives response as

```
Selecting previously unselected package elasticsearch.
(Reading database ... 51009 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking elasticsearch (from elasticsearch-0.90.5.deb) ...
Setting up elasticsearch (0.90.5) ...
Adding system user `elasticsearch' (UID 107) ...
Adding new user `elasticsearch' (UID 107) with group `elasticsearch' ...
Not creating home directory `/usr/share/elasticsearch'.
* Starting ElasticSearch Server                                               [ OK ] 
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

Then started the service with

```
 sudo service elasticsearch start
* Starting ElasticSearch Server                                               [ OK ]
```

After that when i am checking status, it shows

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
* elasticsearch is not running
```

I checked my log, but it is empty.

There is no other process running on port 9200

My java version : "1.6.0_31"

Does anyone have any idea why this happening?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated script for running elasticsearch as a service (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch). The below script solved the issue.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          elasticsearch
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts elasticsearch
# Description:       Starts elasticsearch using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch
ES_MIN_MEM=256m
ES_MAX_MEM=2g
DAEMON=$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch
NAME=elasticsearch
DESC=elasticsearch
PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
#LOG_DIR=/var/log/$NAME
LOG_DIR=/extn1/es_log/
#DATA_DIR=/var/lib/$NAME
DATA_DIR=/extn1/data/
WORK_DIR=/tmp/$NAME
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/$NAME/elasticsearch.yml
DAEMON_OPTS="-p $PID_FILE -Des.config=$CONFIG_FILE -Des.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.path.work=$WORK_DIR"


test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

set -e

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    mkdir -p $LOG_DIR $DATA_DIR $WORK_DIR
    if start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PID_FILE --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
then
        echo "started."
    else
        echo "failed."
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PID_FILE
    then
        echo "stopped."
    else
        echo "failed."
    fi
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    ${0} stop
    sleep 0.5
    ${0} start
    ;;
  *)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try to reduce the memory.
Do the following changes:

1. `vi /opt/elasticsearch-1.3.4/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf`
2. you need to decrease memory (`ES_HEAP_SIZE`) limit. [1024 to 512 etc.]
3. save the file.
4. `service elasticsearch start`

Hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: Note: make sure that that your java version is 7.

Comment: No... i have got the issue.. I changed the shell script for running elasticsearch as a service (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch) with a new script.
Thanks a lot for the reply.